# How can I justify that the partial sums of $\frac{(2n)^k}{k!}$ is less than the number $\frac{(2n)^n}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality, power-series

I am currently using Rouche's Theorem from complex analysis but am working on an upper bound and want to show

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(2n)^k}{k!}< \frac{(2n)^n}{n!}$$

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: I do not know if this could be of any interest $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(2n)^k}{k!}=\frac{e^{2 n} \Gamma (n,2 n)}{\Gamma (n)}$

Comment: @Claude, gamma function representations for the partial sums of $\exp$ have never actually made anything easier :)

Comment: @AntonioVargas. I suspected. I made this comment after your nice, "simple" and elegant answer. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion @ClaudeLeibovici - I need to work on more problems that utilize the gamma function :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0 \leq k \leq n-2$ and $n > 1$ we have

$$
\frac{(2n)^{k+1}/(k+1)!}{(2n)^k/k!} = \frac{2n}{k+1} \geq \frac{2n}{n-1} > 2.
$$

Therefore

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(2n)^k}{k!} < \frac{(2n)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^k} < \frac{(2n)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} 2 = \frac{(2n)^n}{n!}.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution @AntonioVargas :-)